# Spring Boot Security - Postman gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I am developing rest APIs in Spring Boot. I am able to do CRUD operations and postman gives correct responses, but when I add Spring Security username and password Postman gives 401 Unauthorized.

I have provided a spring boot security username and password as below.

application.proptries

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pal?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=root
```

I have done basic auth with username as root and password as root.
Preview request gives headers updated successfully message :

[image]

**EDIT**
[I have deleted the cookies in postman but still facing the same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZYR6.png)

```
SecurityConfing.java
My Security Configuration are as below. 
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1000)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {

        authenticationMgr.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource())
          .usersByUsernameQuery(
           "select email,password from user where email=? and statusenable=true")
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
           "select email,role from user where email=? and statusenable=true");

        System.out.println(authenticationMgr.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource())
          .usersByUsernameQuery(
           "select email,password from user where email=? and statusenable=true")
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
           "select email,role from user where email=? and statusenable=true"));
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
     public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
         driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pal");
         driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
         driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
         return driverManagerDataSource;
     }

    @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER").anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER").anyRequest().permitAll();

}
```

Comment: Please delete the cookies of Postman for this request and try again.

Comment: kamlesh pandey I have deleted the cookies but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/newuser").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/newuser/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/master/*").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/exploreCourse").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    }
}
```

You need to configure Spring Security, by default all routes all secured for authrorization.

Please have a look JWT Token implementation at this [Link](https://github.com/nishant-varshney/Spring-Boot-RestAPI/tree/master/LP_RESTAPI/src/main/java/com/nv/Configuration).

Comment: Nishant Thank you for your answer but still facing the issue, I have updated the question with my with WenSecurityConfiguration. Please have a look.

Comment: What issue you are getting now??

Comment: Nishant, I get the details when I use GET Method but when I try to use POST, PUT or DELETE postman gives 401 Unauthorized/403 Forbidden

Comment: @Romil as per the updated code only /login will not gives you 401. Please have a look at updated answer and permitAll() your APIs for which you dont need any authentication...Moreover you can use JWT Token for APIs which is one of the best way for securing APIs...

Comment: Thanks @Nishant .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/admin/**").permitAll() solve the issue. I will take a look on JWT.

Comment: Any other reason why this problem could happen? I ask because I have mine exactly like yours and I still keep receiving 401 for the `POST` endPoint on `.permitAll()`, for the `GET` It works well, the problem is for the `POST`.

Comment: @FranciscoSouza have you fixed the issue ? I'm facing the same

Comment: Facing same issue. the same code that I have is working on colleague's system

Comment: I saw that on using csrf().disable() the POST, PUT operations started working in Postman tool. Why is it so? If I don't use then I get 401 error

Answer (score 1):

If Authorization needed in spring boot, the below annotation at root configuration class.

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
( and other required annotations)
public class Application{
....
....
}
```

Below dependency also needed to be added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the SecurityAutoConfiguration class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BackendApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```