# How to add spring security parameters in Postman?

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot, spring-security

I have added Spring Security in my project. It's working fine when I am requesting from browser, it simply ask my username and password and gives access to API. But now I tried from Postman. I tried passing username and password fields in headers but it is not allowing me to access API.

I am continuously getting 401 unauthorized in Postman.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758872/spring-boot-security-postman-gives-401-unauthorized) Let me know how its work for you

Answer (score 1):

Simply select "Authorization" tab and then the authorization method. Pretty clear in here https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/

Faor your case choose "Basic" authorization

Answer (score 0):

- first create application security confige class like this :

[image]

- Second go to you postMan and change the authentification type to basic like this :[image]